# Extracting vertices data after transformations

Tags: python, mesh, vertices, transforms

I'm using few rotations and scale changes in a model and then export the location of the vertices after the change, but when I do so, the vertices extracted are those of before the transformations and not after. How can I extract the new vertices?

An example for a transformation:

```
bpy.data.objects["Main"].pose.bones["finger5-.L"].rotation_quaternion[1]=random.uniform(0, 0.4)
```

And the code for extracting the vertices:

```
mesh = bpy.data.objects["Main:Body"]
vertices = mesh.data.vertices
for vertex in vertices:
    vertex1 = vertex.co[0]
    vertex2 = vertex.co[1]
    vertex3 = vertex.co[2]
    row = [vertex1, vertex2, vertex3]
    with open(os.path.join(vertices_output_path, 'vertices.csv'), 'a') as csvFile:
        writer = csv.writer(csvFile)
        writer.writerow(row)
        csvFile.close()
```

Comment: [Related](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57011/how-do-i-get-the-deformed-coordinate-of-a-vertex-with-python) and  [Related](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34789/how-to-get-vertex-coordinates-after-modifier-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

Please search here at BSE for

**matrix_world**

as in

worldc = o1.matrix_world * vertex.co