# How to get vertex coordinates after modifier in Python in Blender 2.80?

Tags: python, modifiers, bones, vertices

I have a mesh with armature modifier. Is there any efficient way to read its vertices coordinates with modifiers accounted in Blender 2.80?

So far the only way I found is to duplicate the object, apply modifier, read vertices and remove duplicated object:

```py
def extract_vertices(my_object):
    # Duplicate object
    for obj in bpy.data.objects: obj.select_set(False)
    my_object.select_set(True)
    bpy.ops.object.duplicate_move()

    # Apply modificators
    duplicated_object = bpy.context.scene.objects[-1]
    bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = duplicated_object
    duplicated_object.select_set(True)
    bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply(apply_as='DATA', modifier="RIG")

    # Read vertices
    vertices = [v.co for v in duplicated_object.data.vertices]

    # Remove duplicated object
    my_object.select_set(False)
    bpy.ops.object.delete()

    return vertices
```

It works, but very slow. I need to run this thing thousands of times in the loop, adjusting modifier every iteration.

It seems that `Object.to_mesh()` [described in answer here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34789/how-to-get-vertex-coordinates-after-modifier-in-python) could be exactly what I need, but it's [signature is changed in Blender2.80](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Object.html?highlight=to_mesh#bpy.types.Object.to_mesh) and there's no `apply_modifiers` parameter anymore.

Comment: Also relevant: https://blenderartists.org/t/2-80-cheat-sheet-for-updating-add-ons/1148974

Comment: @rjg, probably, but not sure. As I newbie I wouldn't immediately figure out how to get vertices coordinates from answers to that question.

Comment: Also the answer here is more complete, IMO. It reminds to do things like `bm.verts.ensure_lookup_table()` and `bm.free()`, which I wouldn't know is needed.

Comment: Sure, no problem lemon's answer is more complete. You don't necessarily need `bm.free()` (you won't create a memory leak if you don't use it), but it is more efficient because it deallocates the memory right away and not just when there is no reference anymore. It's always a good idea to check the Blender Python API docs (https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bmesh.html)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using bmesh and the dependencies graph, you can get an evaluated bmesh:

```
import bpy
import bmesh

depsgraph = bpy.context.evaluated_depsgraph_get()

obj = bpy.data.objects['Cube']

bm = bmesh.new()

bm.from_object( obj, depsgraph )

bm.verts.ensure_lookup_table()

print( "----" )
for v in bm.verts:
    print( v.co )

bm.free()
```

Edit:

obj.to_mesh should work too (have not tested) but if you don't want to create a mesh, this is not needed.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I spent hours hitting the wall! Should I call `bpy.context.evaluated_depsgraph_get()` every time I update modifiers? Or once at initialization is enough?

Comment: @AndriiZymohliad, you should call it each time in my opinion. Untested, but it is logical to think that this is a data structure as another so nothing updates it automatically. Please, add a comment here if you test that (should be simple to do with a modifier, simple deform for instance, and a keyframe on it).

Comment: It seems to work with just a single initialization of depsgraph. I guess the getter just obtains some sort of handle to it and is cheap anyway.