# Blender 2.8 vertices of object doesn't update after location change in python

Tags: python, mesh, scripting, .fbx

I import a .fbx object and move the location. Then I try to print the local coordinates of the object. Regardless of where I move it, it prints the same local coordinates leading to me believe that the mesh vertices are not being updated. The snippet is attached below.

```
bpy.ops.import_scene.fbx( filepath = "sample.fbx" )
myObj  = bpy.data.objects['testObj']
print (myObj.data.vertices[0].co)
myObj.location = mathutils.Vector((1,3,5))
print (myObj.data.vertices[0].co)
```

This prints the same values both times. How do I update it? I would appreciate an answer for Blender 2.8

Comment: For 2.7x and before, but related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/94034/i-dont-know-what-is-wrong-with-my-python-script  Vertex coordinates are in local space.  Can move a mesh object anywhere in the scene by setting the objects transform (translation, rotation, scale) without altering the vertex coordinates.  This is a fundamental of 3d maths eg one default  cube has local coordinates existing of the 8 combinations of +/- 1 (-1, -1, -1) , (-1, -1, 1) ...  (1, 1, 1) that remain unchanged no matter how it is transformed.  As shown in the answer below object transform is used to

Comment: place local objects into our global space.   Put another way object transforms don't change the local data.  If you wish to transorm the data not the object use `myObj.data.transform(Matrix.Translation((1, 3, 5)))` to translate all local coordinates by (1, 3, 5)

Comment: I now understand local coordinates. So if want to change my location of the object and get the global coordinates of the vertices, I should use Matrix.Translation to move it and then pre-multiply with matrix_world ? I cannot get the global coordinates of the vertices by setting the myObj.location?

Answer (score 3):

For the scene global coordinate system, multiply by the object's world matrix:

```
myObj  = bpy.data.objects['testObj']
print (myObj.data.vertices[0].co)
myObj.location = mathutils.Vector((1,3,5))
print (myObj.matrix_world @ myObj.data.vertices[0].co) # <----
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is to be run in blender 2.9 It explain how to get or convert local coordinates of a vertex to global coordinates.

```
#############################################################
# imports :
import bpy
from mathutils import Vector

#############################################################
# Add a Cube and Get the initial local coordinates of vertex id 0,
# Get the initial Cube matrix_world,
# Calculate the initial vertex id 0 Global Coordinates :

bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add()
Cube  = bpy.context.object
Mw = Cube.matrix_world
Vert0_Lco = Cube.data.vertices[0].co
Vert0_Gco = Mw @ Vert0_Lco

print (f"Vert 0 initial Local coordinates :\n{Vert0_Lco}") # should be (-1, -1, -1)
print (f"Cube initial Matrix world :\n{Mw}") # should be the identity Matrix
print (f"Vert 0 initial Global coordinates :\n{Vert0_Gco}") # should be (-1, -1, -1) also

#############################################################
# Make a translation vector :
# Translate the cube,
# Get the final Cube matrix_world,
# Calculate the final vertex id 0 Global Coordinates :

Trans_Vector = Vector((1,3,5))

'''Now If you want the Cube matrix_world to be updated after the translation transform dont use<<< Cube.location = Trans_Vector >>>, instead use :'''

Mw.translation += Trans_Vector

print (f"Vert 0 final Local coordinates :\n{Vert0_Lco}")#Should be the same ( (-1, -1, -1) dont change after transform)
print (f"Cube final Matrix world :\n{Mw}") # should change to :
'''
Matrix(((1, 0, 0, 1 )
        (0, 1, 0, 3 )
        (0, 0, 1, 5 )
        (0, 0, 0, 1 )))
'''
print (f"Vert 0 final Global coordinates :\n{Vert0_Gco}") # should change to (0, 2, 4)
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer. Code only answers are frowned upon here. What does this code do, what is its purpose and how does it work? Could you add a short explanation of what you did here?