# Location along actual (beveled) curve instead of points

Tags: python, bezier-curves, path, bevel

The following code generates a tree root structure, by making each sub-root start at a point along the previous sub-root. They are all NURBS paths. The hitch, as you will see, is that the points are not inside the visible beveled curve, and therefore the sub-root's origin point gets off-set. What code should I write to make sure that the sub-roots always start inside the visible part of their parent root, instead of the points?

[I've made a screencast](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1oMzKgJAPvvTZxzKCF32MaWOZDUx9rPVM) to show what the problem is. I need a way to resolve it in the code itself, to make the whole model generative without assistance.

**Update**: here's the blender file [image]

```
import bpy
import random
import mathutils

def pathPointLoc(cpath, points):        #uses the locations in the lsit (points) to shape the curve

    cpath.points.add(len(points)-1)

    for (index, point) in enumerate(points):
        cpath.points[index].co = point

    cpath.use_endpoint_u = True

    return

cu = bpy.data.curves.new("root", "CURVE")       #lines 16-26: generates the NURBS path curve for the tap (main) root
ob = bpy.data.objects.new("taproot", cu)        #these are not in a for loop because there only needs to be one tap root
polyline = cu.splines.new('NURBS')

scn = bpy.context.scene
scn.objects.link(ob)
scn.objects.active = ob

cu.dimensions = '3D'
cu.bevel_object = bpy.data.objects["circle1"]   #bezier circle, for bevel and consistent taper; circle1 is largest, circle3 is smallest
cu.taper_object = bpy.data.objects["circle1"]

x = random.randint(1,5)
y = random.randint(1,5)
z = 1                                           #keeping z axis constant, only need it to operate on x and y for now
w = 1                                           #honestly no idea what this element does but 4 values are necessary for the syntax

print("X and Y are "+str(x)+" and "+str(y))     #just to keep track of the values, not essential

if y > x:                                       #the curves behave strangely when y is less than x, hence this statement
    x = random.randint(y,y+2)
    print ("Revised values of above X and Y: "+str(x)+" and "+str(y))

tap_ur = (x,y,z,w)
tap_pts = [tap_ur]                              #ur for origin, because this is the base of each curve

for tapinc in range(1,9):                       #loop apends location tuples for each point on the curve, after the first one is defined

    y_noise = round(random.uniform(-1,1))*3     #since this curve has to move further on the x axis than the y, the y has a small - and + motion
    while y_noise == 0:
        y_noise = round(random.uniform(-1,1))*3 #0 avoided to keep the curve meandering, not constant

    x_noise = round(random.uniform(1,2))*3
    while x_noise == 0:
        x_noise = round(random.uniform(1,2))*3

    y += y_noise                                #meanders the curve
    x += x_noise                                #ensure that the next point on the curve is further along

    tap_nxt = list(tap_ur)                      #converting tuple to list in order to change x and y
    tap_nxt[0] = x
    tap_nxt[1] = y

    tap_pts.append(tap_nxt)

tap_pts.reverse()                               #because the curve takes locations from right left in the list; could have switched the path's direction instead but this is simpler

pathPointLoc(polyline, tap_pts)

for sub1 in range (1,len(tap_pts)):             #subroot, tier 1: looped version of the code from 16-61; note that the number of subroots depends on the length of the parent root

    cu = bpy.data.curves.new("root", "CURVE")
    ob = bpy.data.objects.new("subroot_1_"+str(sub1), cu)
    polyline = cu.splines.new('NURBS')

    scn = bpy.context.scene
    scn.objects.link(ob)
    scn.objects.active = ob

    cu.dimensions = '3D'
    cu.bevel_object = bpy.data.objects["circle2"]
    cu.taper_object = bpy.data.objects["circle2"]

    sub1_ur = random.choice(tap_pts[2:len(tap_pts)-1])
    sub1_pts = [sub1_ur]

    x = sub1_ur[0]                              #inheriting/resetting x and y values
    y = sub1_ur[1]

    for sub1inc in range(1,5):

        x_noise = round(random.uniform(-1,1))*2 #since this root tier is perpendicular to the parent one, x meanders it and y pushes it along
        while x_noise == 0:
            x_noise = round(random.uniform(-1,1))*2

        y_noise = round(random.uniform(1,2))*2
        while y_noise == 0:
            y_noise = round(random.uniform(1,2))*2

        x += x_noise

        if sub1%2 != 0:
            y += y_noise
        else:
            y -= y_noise

        sub1_nxt = list(sub1_ur)
        sub1_nxt[0] = x
        sub1_nxt[1] = y

        sub1_pts.append(sub1_nxt)

    x = sub1_ur[0]                              #resetting x and y to prevent carry-over
    y = sub1_ur[1]

    sub1_pts.reverse()

    pathPointLoc(polyline, sub1_pts)

    for sub2 in range (1,len(sub1_pts)):

        cu = bpy.data.curves.new("root", "CURVE")
        ob = bpy.data.objects.new("subroot_2_"+str((sub1-1)+sub2), cu)
        polyline = cu.splines.new('NURBS')

        scn = bpy.context.scene
        scn.objects.link(ob)
        scn.objects.active = ob

        cu.dimensions = '3D'
        cu.bevel_object = bpy.data.objects["circle3"]
        cu.taper_object = bpy.data.objects["circle3"]

        sub2_ur = random.choice(sub1_pts[2:len(sub1_pts)-1])
        sub2_pts = [sub2_ur]

        x = sub2_ur[0]
        y = sub2_ur[1]

        for sub2inc in range(1,5):

            y_noise = round(random.uniform(-1,1))
            while y_noise == 0:
                y_noise = round(random.uniform(-1,1))

            x_noise = round(random.uniform(1,2))
            while x_noise == 0:
                x_noise = round(random.uniform(1,2))        
            y += y_noise

            if sub2%2 != 0:
                x += x_noise
            else:
                x -= x_noise

            sub2_nxt = list(sub2_ur)
            sub2_nxt[0] = x
            sub2_nxt[1] = y

            sub2_pts.append(sub2_nxt)

        x = sub2_ur[0]
        y = sub2_ur[1]

        sub2_pts.reverse()

        pathPointLoc(polyline, sub2_pts)
```

Comment: I have tried to use the code markup for your code. It looks slightly weird, could you verify that everything is still correct and make an edit if neceessary. Every code line has to have 4 additional spaces at the start in order to be parsed as code.

Comment: Sorry! I posted this in a hurry, hence the bad formatting. Have corrected it, and added comments + screencast.

Comment: Any suggestions?

Comment: Consider also adding a blend file https://blend-exchange.com  The code requires existing objects eg "circle1".

Comment: Done! Sorry, should have added that earlier

Comment: Code wise check out ; [Related](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/34276/15543)  Another way would be to use empty with a follow path constraint where  offset 0 is at one end, 1 the other to place your next level of roots.  In both cases will remove the need to be at the knot.

Comment: Thank you for that! It's a good idea. I've implemented it, so now the empty moves perfectly along the path. However, I can't figure out how to get the empty's location at any given keyframe. `location` and `delta_location` are always at 0, and I can't understand how to use `matrix_world`. If I can access the location data, that point would become the base for the next roots and problem solved.