# How to get every resolution vertice's coordinates of Nurbs curve instead of control point without converting mesh

Tags: python, bezier-curves, nurbs-surface

How to get every resolution vertice's coordinates of Nurbs curve instead of control point without converting mesh using python?
That is get the green point's coordinate

[image: image description]

Comment: i found [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34145/calculate-points-on-a-nurbs-curve-without-converting-to-mesh) but the answer seems incorrect as of 2022.

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie Thank you for your help! I didn't notice your answer until now. I have tried many methods since then, but I think the problem seems insurmountable.

Comment: The control points are a continuous representation of all possible points along the segment. It's basically an interpolation function. This problem is far far far easier than you realize.