# How to set objects , or vertex point in a bezier resolution_u vertex?

Tags: python, vertices, bezier-curves

I'm trying to approach the beziers, but I'm still not able to understand the situations, so I based myself on a part of this code coming from
[Getting the list of points that describe a Curve without converting to mesh](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/688/getting-the-list-of-points-that-describe-a-curve-without-converting-to-mesh/689#689)

In this case as a test I am trying to place a series of cubes in the positions of resolution_u, without success, since when I modify the bezier, the points are always the same, in addition they do not match with the global space, I am not sure that they should be converted with a matrix operation, I don't understand how.
In addition I would like to take into account the rotation of these points, so that the cubes actually follow the trend of the curve with the related twists

```
import bpy ,bmesh ,mathutils

spline = bpy.data.curves[0].splines[0]

if len(spline.bezier_points) >= 2:
    r = spline.resolution_u + 1
    segments = len(spline.bezier_points)
    if not spline.use_cyclic_u:
        segments -= 1

    points = []
    for i in range(segments):
        inext = (i + 1) % len(spline.bezier_points)

        knot1 = spline.bezier_points[i].co
        handle1 = spline.bezier_points[i].handle_right
        handle2 = spline.bezier_points[inext].handle_left
        knot2 = spline.bezier_points[inext].co

        _points = mathutils.geometry.interpolate_bezier(knot1, handle1, handle2, knot2, r)
        points.extend(_points)


for v in points:

    mesh = bpy.data.meshes.new('Cube')
    cube = bpy.data.objects.new('Cube', mesh)                      
    bm = bmesh.new()
    bmesh.ops.create_cube(bm, size=0.1)
    bm.to_mesh(mesh)
    bm.free()
    bpy.context.scene.collection.objects.link(cube)
    bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = cube

    cube.location = v
```

The result I get is this, I am completely in the dark with this type of operation, I hope you have patience.
[image]